# unity add an object as a child

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent-child, gameobject

I have a moving object containing some objects.

When i'm creating some of the child objects and setting the parent to parent object, the created object does not move with parent.

I checked the hierarchy panel. but the created objects are not in the parents as a child.

this is my code:

```
GameObject parent = GameObject.Find ("Ground");
clone.transform.parent = parent.transform;
```

What is the problem?

Comment: code looks fine, but does the code actually run?

Comment: Yes it runs. because when i'm debugging, it prints Objects name.

Comment: not sure if it's involved in the problem but transform.parent is a "Transform" data type according to the documentation, not a GameObject data type; so it's having to convert that behind the scenes.

Comment: Code is just fine and working. Please recheck if GameObject.Find is giving you the proper object by Logs or Break Points.